# Import module in React component for publish on NPM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

It's my first React component for publication in NPM. I use *react-webpack-component* package from **Yeoman** to start my project. But when I install and import my component to React app, I catch error:

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./~/kladrapi-react/index.js
Module not found: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin] `/develop/myproject/node_modules/kladrapi-react/node_modules/React/react.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk `react`.

 @ ./~/kladrapi-react/index.js 1:82-98
```

I'm understand this error, but not understand how correctly import React modules to my component!

[Actual version on GitHub](https://github.com/vUdav/kladrapi-react/tree/feature/single_content)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are multiple issues in your code.

In `index.html`:

@line-- `<script src="kladrapi-react.js"></script>`

1. The file name is "kladrapi-react.jsx"  not "kladrapi-react.js".
2. Second issue, here you are expecting "kladrapi-react.js(x)" to be on root level. Which is not the case. According to your folder structure "kladrapi-react.js(x)" file is at ./lib/kladrapi-react.jsx.

Apart from this, in your kladrapi-react.js(x) file you have mixed ES5 and ES6 syntax. You are accessing the variable `KladrapiReact` in `index.html` but you haven't exported it as 'KladrapiReact'. I would recommend you to put `'React.createClass....'` code in a separate component.

**For the error you are receiving you need to use 'case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin':**

This Webpack plugin enforces the entire path of all required modules match the exact case of the actual path on disk.

```
npm install --save-dev case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin
```

**Usage:**

```
var CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');

var webpackConfig = {
    plugins: [
        new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin()
        // other plugins ...
    ]
    // other webpack config ...
}
```

For more info on this plugin read documentation [here](https://github.com/Urthen/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin).

Answer (score -1):

Module not found: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin] `/develop/myproject/node_modules/kladrapi-react/node_modules/React/react.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk `react`.

@ ./~/kladrapi-react/index.js